# how to declare array

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I need someones help to declare the following array:-

```
self.tablePicture = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pic1.png", @"pic2.png", @"Country.png", nil];
```

for:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

// Configure the cell.
cell.textLabel.text = @"cell text";
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[tablePicture objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
}
```

How do I do I apply it in .h and .m files? I am fairly new to this.

Thanks in advance :)

PS. When I apply to the following I get "pic1.png" repeated and no array.

```
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Region", @"Subregion", @"Country",      @"County", @"City", @"District", nil];
self.tablePicture = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pic1.png", @"pic2.png", @"Country.png", nil];
CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
frame.size.height -= 100;
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

[self.view addSubview:self.tableView]; 
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: Array seems fine, do check @beryllium answer below for .h & .m stuff below. But do you mean no cells being output? If so have you implemented the UITableView Datasource and have these methods: – numberOfSectionsInTableView:
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tablePicture;
```

.m

```
@synthesize tablePicture;

...

-(void)dealloc{
    [tablePicture release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: That's great but I get seem to only get the first "pic1.png" repeated for each of the respective table cells

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property for your array in your View Controller's .h file:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tablePicture;
```

Set the value of your array property in the `ViewDidLoad` method of your View Controller's .m file:

```
@synthesize tablePicture;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tablePicture = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pic1.png", @"pic2.png", @"Country.png", nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks it half works but doesn't array just "pic1.png" repeating itself... see edit above

Comment: Do you have more than one section in your tableView?  If would be useful to also see your implementations for `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:`

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.tableData.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem could be outside of your array initialization.

Why don't you try adding:

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.tablePicture);
```

after the line

```
"self.tablePicture = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pic1.png", @"pic2.png", @"Country.png", nil];"
```

Comment: I tried, but still only pic1.png repeating itself :(